# How do I use font families on pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fonts, pygame, font-family

I installed 'Raleway' a while ago, and can't seem to make it work for pygame. My program seems to only be able to display the regular version of the font, but not bold, italics, etc. Here's what I have:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Raleway Bold', 72)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((850, 600))
done = False

while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        done = True

        screen.fill((8, 8, 8))
        textsurface = myfont.render('WELCOME', False, (205, 92, 92))
        screen.blit(textsurface,(250,200))
```

And here's the fonts available under the font family:
[Raleway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69gkN.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your font is actually just named `Raleway`, and to load the bold version, you have to [set the `bold` flag](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.SysFont):

```
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Raleway', 72, bold=True, italic=False)
```

Comment: Ok thanks. If I want to access 'extra bold' or 'medium', what would I need to do?